# I want to know if there is any way to add new tuple without disturbing the current sequence of the data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5haR.jpg)

I am saving data in my SQL for my school homework

I don't want to update all that data one by one because it is too much would definitely end up finishing it up in the morning.

So I want to automatically update the data when I will modify it

as an example, if the sequence of the data is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, .... and so on.

If add a data should on the place of 2nd position so the serial number of 2nd will automatically get updated to 3rd and 3rd to fourth and so on.

Hope I defined well .

Thanks for your help.... have a nice day :)

Comment: can you show some examples?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5haR.jpg Yeah it's here I want to add another student name but this student's roll no. which is supposed to be was already occupied and if I add that anyway this will disturb the sequence

Comment: Please share more details, like your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: for example.you want add new student which roll_no is 1202.so exists 1202 will become to 1203.and 1203=>1204 and so on?

Comment: yes exactly nay but i can't figure it out how to do it

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing. You should at least share your attempts

Comment: For example, I want to add a new student which roll_no is 1202.so exists 1202 will become 1203.and 1203=>1204 and so on?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - afterwards, edit your question to contain all relevant information, like the table structure, and your attempts to resolve the question. Also, please explain what you mean by "automatically get updated"? Are you looking for something like auto increment?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `roll_no` is an arbitrary unique identifier, the position shouldn't matter.

Comment: Thanks so much, Barmar for your help. That did figure out my problem thanks man really.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right but better know I think. Now you told me that I am feeling dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to insert and automatically push all the other sequence numbers up. You need to do that explicitly.

```
UPDATE students
SET roll_no = roll_no + 1
WHERE roll_no >= 1202
ORDER BY roll_no DESC;

INSERT INTO students (roll_no, name, marks)
VALUES (1202, 'New Name', 400);
```

`ORDER BY roll_no DESC` is important so you don't create duplicates during the process.